# Disappearing Input

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
 <a href="test" id="w" target="_blank"><input type="image" id="button1" src="button.png" /></a>
```

CSS

```
#w:target {
display: none;
}
```

Any idea why this isn't working properly?
Full script:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2NMZ/180/#&togetherjs=wwKcmVHQRN

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Make the button disappear on click @MiltoxBeyond

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond On this website I want the Link buttons to go away. http://terminusprison.com/vote/

Comment: That's not how css works... If you want to do something like that you will need to research javascript.

Comment: Actually it can work just you are doing it slightly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem was that you were using the :target selector on the wrong element.  It should be attached to the actual element you want to disappear.  Then you just create an anchor to that element with the target in the form of `href="#ID-OF-ELEMENT"`.  Afterwards you just make sure the element has the proper ID so it links correctly.

I made a simpler example for you to see how to do it.

```css
a { display:block; }

input.hideable{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #AAA;
}

.hideable:target {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#testInput">HideInput</a>
<input src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" class="hideable" type="image" placeholder="Test" id="testInput" />

<a href="#testInput2">HideInput</a>
<input src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" class="hideable" type="image" placeholder="Test" id="testInput2" />

<a href="#testInput3">HideInput</a>
<input class="hideable" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" type="image" placeholder="Test" id="testInput3" />
```

#### Updated to use `input[type="image"]`

To remove permanently via jquery:

```js
$('body').on('click','a.do-hide',function(event) { 
          event.preventDefault(); 
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          $(href).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#button1" class="do-hide">Hide Button</a>

<div id="button1">Hide Me</div>
```

Comment: The only issue is Im using type="image" and it doesnt seem to work. 
    <a href="test" id="w" target="_blank"><input class="hideable"      type="image" id="button1" src="button.png" /></a> a { display:block; }

    input.hideable{
    display:block;
     border:1px solid #AAA;
     }

.hideable:target {
  display:none;
}

Comment: I just updated it to use `type="image"`.  You need to change the `<a href="test"` to say `<a href="#button1"`

Comment: And make sure each link points to a button like that, without target="_blank"

Comment: Okay I did that the only issue is I want after you click the button on  http://terminusprison.com/vote/ the button disappears permanently because the issue I have is now the button comes back after you click the next one.

Comment: That is what happens indeed.  If you want it to disappear permanently you have to either use the checkbox/label css trick or go through javascript

Comment: Ahhh what a shame do you have any examples?

Comment: Thinking about it the CSS version wouldn't work, if you click twice on the label the button returns.  You probably are better off with something in javascript. I'll update the answer

Comment: Where would I put the $('body').on('click','a.do-hide',function(event) { 
          event.preventDefault(); 
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          $(href).hide();
});

Comment: @MitoxBeyond Could you take a look here and tell me whats wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=qE6MuJgrfq